# Protect php files from direct access

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is what the map of my website looks like:

```
root:
     -index.php
     -\actions\ (various php files inside and a .htaccess)
     - \includes\ (various php files inside and a .htaccess)
     - .htaccess
```

I know that if I use "deny from all" in actions and includes directories, the files in them will be secured from direct access.

Now, my actions folder has many php files that are called by `index.php` (forms).
I have "deny from all" in `.htaccess` inside `\actions`, but then I have the forbiden access to that files.

So, how can I protect the files from direct url access but have the exception that can be called from `index.php`?

Comment: I have made some edits to the question but I left the ending intact since I don't know if you are getting a "forbidden access" exception and want to get rid of it, or if you want to force that exception to be thrown in case of a direct url access. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to place a constant in the index.php and check in the other php files if this constant exists. If not, let the script die.

index.php

```
define('APP', true);
```

various.php

```
if(!defined('APP')) die();
```

Comment: A friendlier alternative to `die()`: `header('Location:/index.php')`

Comment: Thank you. Will use your way  :)

Comment: Nice, please mark as answer for other persons searching for this ;-)

Comment: Comment for "George" ... header('Location:/index.php') is a friendlier alternative but not secured one. robots are not put attention to "headers" what means the script will keep to run even if the "header" is changed. you have to add die(); after the header location...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to block using `.htaccess` then most likely the best way of adding the exception is to add it to the same `.htaccess` file. If you want to prevent PHP script from working (but not from being "visible"), then simply look for certain condition (like session variable, constant) at the begining of your scripts. Unless these scripts are invoked "the right way", these requirement will not be ment, so it'd be safe to just `die()` then

Comment: If you do the `.htaccess` trick, it's recommended to use `httpd.conf` instead, if you have access to it.